# Erase first line from a string

Tags: c++, string, iterator

What is the simplest way to erase the first line from a string?

Example:

> "abc\ndef\nghi"
>
> =>
>
> "def\nghi"

Comment: What ways have you tried before asking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use the `.find` to find where the first `\n` is and then use the `.erase` to remove starting from the first character to where you found `\n`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string myString = "abc\ndef\nghi";
    myString.erase(0, myString.find("\n") + 1);
    std::cout << myString;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Caesar's answer fails when the source is MacOS because:

- \n => Un*x
- \r\n => windows
- \r => MacOS

A better way using boost::regex could be :

```
boost::regex kNewLine("\r\n|\n|\r");
boost::split_regex(oSplitMessage, iRawMessage, kNewLine);
```

I hope it helps.